# Change the color of polyline in android google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have this code found from this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#customizing_appearances

```
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298), new LatLng(-31.95285, 115.85734))
    .width(25)
    .color(Color.BLUE)
    .geodesic(true));
```

My Problem is **Color** in **Color.Blue** returns an error saying The name Color does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already solved my problem.

First I created an xml file in my values folder Color.xml

**Color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#0000EE</color>
</resources>
```

Then in my Activity

```
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .Add(new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298), new LatLng(-31.95285, 115.85734))
    .InvokeColor(Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.blue));
```

Answer (score 10):

Just define a color in your `colors` resources file and do this:

```
PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(4).color(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.cyan));
```

Works great for me.

Comment: I used it but still **.Color** returns an error "Non-invocable member Android.Gms.Maps.Model.PolylineOptions.Color cannot be used like a method"

Comment: Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298), new LatLng(-31.95285, 115.85734))
    .width(25)
    .color(Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.blue))
    .geodesic(true));

Comment: And I made an xml file for color file

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
lineOptions.addAll(points);
lineOptions.width(12);
lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE); //this is for color
lineOptions.geodesic(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, work for me.

```
lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
lineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
PolylineOptions polyline_options = new PolylineOptions()
                        .addAll(arraylist_lat_lon).color(Color.GREEN).width(2);

                polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polyline_options);
```

Before this,
 add **color xml** to you **values** folder, and define all colors what you want.
Just like this manner:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <color name="blue">#82CAFF</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="symptom_color_selected">#003366</color>
    <color name="reaction_color_selected">#003366</color>
    <color name="static_text_color">#003366</color>
    <color name="journal_entry_listitem_text_color">#003366</color>
    <color name="note_text_disabled">#333333</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
    <color name="navy">#6699FF</color>
    <color name="sky">#0099CC</color>
    <color name="gray">#808080</color>
    <color name="lightgray">#e7e7e7</color>
    <color name="lightgray02">#bfbfbf</color>
    <color name="dark">#000015</color>
    <color name="lightgreen">#336666</color>
    <color name="orrange">#e33d1b</color>
    <color name="darkorrange">#cc2303</color>
    <color name="pressed_color">#FF8E4067</color>
    <color name="focussed_color">#DD8E4067</color>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating too many short `Polylines` just create one like here:

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
```

> Here, sets geodesic(true) whether to draw each segment of the line
>   as a geodesic or not.

Answer (score 1):

Another working solution is:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
```

and then use:

```
Color.BLUE
```

to represent the blue color like you did the fist time. No need to create the Color.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was just this:

```
                      lineoptions.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorP));
```

Where colorP is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><resources><color name="colorP">#ff8100</color></resources>
```

in color file

Answer (score 0):

The right answer as of Android 6.0 is to use `R.color` directly:

```java
PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(4).color(R.color.cyan);
```